# YouTube API Flash Player Scale Issues

Tags: flash, browser, youtube-api, scale

I have a swf file which loads the YouTube API player at 640px by 400px:

```
function onPlayerReady(event:Event):void {
  trace("player ready:", Object(event).data);
  player = loader.content;
  player.cueVideoById( t***Path  , "0" , "medium");
  player.setSize(640 , 360 );
  player.playVideo();
  player.setVolume(65);
  player.x = 0;
  player.y = 0;
  var url2:String;
```

}

However I've received questions from visitors to our site concerning the scale of the video when they zoom in and out with their browser. When the browser zooms out the video stays retains the 640 x 400 dimensions effectively clipping the viewing area inside the parent div which has an overflow of display none. I've attached images to illustrate the specific issue. Image one is original scale, the second is when the browser is zoomed out. Links to images:

1. https://s3.amazonaws.com/anuk/players/og-scale.jpg
2. https://s3.amazonaws.com/anuk/players/zoomed-out.jpg

Any ideas? Thanks,
CMP

Answer (score 0):

Chris Coyier provides a tutorial to control your YT video sizes [here.](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-youtube-videos/)